# Issue with wso2 api manager permission for roles

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have two instances of wso2 api manager running on two different servers.Both of them are referring to same UM_DB . I created a role by logging with admin credentials on one server .After that i checked for the role on other server by logging with admin credentials again.I found that there was role existing on other server but permission that i provided for that role does not exist on another server.Is that a bug with wso2 api manager or I missed something in configuration..?

Comment: Have you updated user-mgt.xml with UM_DB in both nodes?

Comment: Fine.Its working now.

Comment: now i am not able to create an API with a user having newly defined role. Even though i have associated all permission with that role.However i am able to do it with admin user on another server.

Comment: Did you configure the two servers as a cluster?

Comment: yes! i have followed the document http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager

Answer (score 1):

You want to deploy two APIM instances in a cluster. It is better to refer the APIM clustering [guide](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Deploying+and+Clustering+the+API+Manager) to setup it properly. There are tow things you need to understand.. when your deploying APIM in cluster

1. You must point both instance in to same database. There are can be three logical databases i.e UM, Registry and AM database. These three can be an one physical DB. However must pointed to same by the both instance.
2. You must configure the Hazelcast based clustering using axis2.xml file. This is required because, APIM uses Hazelcast based implementation to distribute the data in the caches. Sometime, In your scenario, i guess you have not configured this. Therefore permission tree has not been distributed between two nodes. Therefore lot of data that is stored in the caches for high performance. therefore please make sure to configure this properly.

I guess this would help you.

Comment: can you share me details how to edit axi2.xml file..?

Comment: you can find the details from http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29918203  Please check  the topic "Setting up cluster configurations for the worker nodes"